# Laravel Relationship function not get data properly?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 Models in My Laravel App like Employee , Salary and Title. Employee Model one to Many Relationship with both Salary and Title Models. Now I need get all data using EmployeeController `getEmployee` function

EmployeeController

```
public function getEmployee() {
        return response()->json(Employee::with('titles','salaries')->get(), 200);
      
    }
```

and my api route is following

```
Route::get('employees','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@getEmployee');
```

but when I try get above data I could get only Employee Model data like this
`[{"emp_no":1,"birth_date":"2014-04-09","first_name":"Marukoi","last_name":"Ashikawa","gender":"male","hire_date":"2023-09-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"titles":[],"salaries":[]}]`

titles and salaries table data not retrieve and empty array.how could I fix this matter?

---

Employee Model

```
 public function titles(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Title::class, 'emp_no');
    }

    public function salaries(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Salary::class, 'emp_no');
    }
}
```

Salary Model

```
 public function employee(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
    }
```

Title Model

```
public function employee(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
    }
```

Comment: Could you maybe add the database schemas for `Employee`, `Title` and `Salary`? I imagine that your defined relationship in your `Employee` model doesn't fit the target.

Comment: @Repox what did you mean?

Comment: Share what your database table structures look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think everything looks good but the issue is your custom foreign and primary key. Try something like

```
    public function titles(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Title::class, 'emp_no', 'emp_no');
    }

    public function salaries(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Salary::class, 'emp_no', 'emp_no');
    }
```

Please check the following documentation from [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

```
return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'foreign_key');
 
return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use array inside "with". `public function getEmployee() { return response()->json(Employee::with(['titles','salaries'])->get(), 200); }`.
It should work for you.